# How to create a maven plugin by using Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, plugins

I am creating a Maven plugin following the maven tutorial https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html.

As my plugin is complex, I want to take advantage of Spring Boot projects (modules like Spring data Neo4j and others). My question is how can I use Spring Boot to create a maven plugin? Any example is appreciated if possible.

Comment: First what is the purpose of the plugin? Apart from that ... in general you can use more or less everything as a dependency in your plugin... but be wise... You can't use spring boot to create maven project... you can create a maven project which is using spring boot as a framework... What are you really like to do? What have you don't so far? What are the problems you have been faced with?

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your answer. Actually, there were no problems while using some other dependencies. At this moment I am using the Neo4J dependency and it works as expected. So I've moved to Spring Data Neo4J in order to have more robust and out-of-the-box implementations. Anyways I just wanted to know if i could use Spring Boot, and once again thanks for your answer, now i know that its not possible

Comment: I have not written that it is not possible. I have written check exactly if the way to create a plugin is the right thing...Maybe it's easier to create JUnit Jupiter extension or alike to handle you use case...